# Leaderboard configuration error

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I'm trying to implement a leaderboard in my game, for the first time.
I created everything on the google dev console, my app, my game service, and so on.

When I try it, I can successfully log in with my google account, but when I try to access the leaderboard, the google game service crashes, and I have the following error in my logs :

```
E/Volley  (30349): [22441] a.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/my-leaderboard-id?language=fr_FR
E/GamesServer(30349): Attempting to access a resource for another application. Check your resource IDs.
E/MultiDataOperation(30349): Attempt to access application XXX from application YYY.
E/MultiDataOperation(30349): com.google.android.gms.games.h.c.a
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.h.b.a(SourceFile:146)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.h.a.bq.a(SourceFile:79)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.a.av.b(SourceFile:1249)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.a.av.b(SourceFile:1227)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.a.av.a(SourceFile:880)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.a.av.a(SourceFile:849)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.a.q.a(SourceFile:561)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.service.a.f.d.a(SourceFile:46)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.service.a.b.a(SourceFile:54)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesIntentService.a(SourceFile:875)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at com.google.android.gms.common.app.c.run(SourceFile:101)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/MultiDataOperation(30349):             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

my-leaderboard-id in the url is properly setted
XXX = Unknown project ID
YYY = My project ID in my games service page

I properly setted my app_id to YYY.
I made a search in my project on XXX, just in case, not found, I have no idea where it comes from.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found out the problem by myself. 
Seems that when I first tried my app, the project id in the app wasn't correct, and this wrong ID had been linked to the leaderboard.

After a proper config, I deleted and recreated the leaderboard, and it now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just recently. Very annoying in an app that is already published and you do not wish to re-create everything.

My leaderboard worked on some device/user but not on others. Finally I figured it did not seem to work on the devices/users that had been used for testing with the initial wrong app ID.

My guess is, if you access your leaderboards from a device using an app with the wrong ID, Google Play services caches the data in the device and keeps using it. So that device permanently makes the wrong leaderboard -
 app ID association. Clearing the cache and deleting all data from Google Play services on my affected device fixed this error for me.